# LinearGradient hide the border color in android when using borderWidth

Tags: android, css, react-native, border, linear-gradients

Im trying to create a circle with an image inside it that its border is colourful that's why I used LinearGradient.

I was using this guide:

https://codeburst.io/linear-gradient-for-border-color-in-react-native-5bcab3eea1c9

the problem that in iOS its working fine as you can see in this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNBRG.jpg

but on android the when I use borderWidth and choosing borderColor of transparent the borderColor looks like shadow and not picking the LinearGradient color from some reason...

here is the android:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7r3n.jpg

what am I doing wrong?

```
        <LinearGradient
          colors={['#ac8af8', '#cca5e7']}
          start={{ x: 0.0, y: 1.0 }} end={{ x: 1.0, y: 1.0 }}
          style={styles.profilePhotoContainer}
        >
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleEditProfileImage.bind(this)}>
            <Image
          style={[styles.profileImage]}
          source={this.state.profilePhoto}
        />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </LinearGradient>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
profilePhotoContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    zIndex: 50,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: Dimensions.get('window').height * .13,
    left: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2 - Dimensions.get('window').width * .13,
    elevation: 4,
    borderRadius: 52,
    borderWidth: 4,
    overflow: "hidden" ,
    borderColor: 'transparent',
  },
profileImage: {
    zIndex: 5,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 50,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'transparent',
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    flex:1,
    resizeMode:'contain',
  },

})
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: anyone has idea?